# Как скрыть номер телефона от поисковиков.

Tags: seo, html

noindex - это только для Яндекса. 
Есть ли какой-нибудь универсальный метод?

Comment: Сделайте его картинкой

Comment: или вставляй его с помощью jquery

Comment: так же, как пытаются прятать email адреса - поищите, полно решений.

Comment: Сделай что-то тпа метода, короч когда пользователь заходит и начинает шевелить мышкой, то появляется номер)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Картинки индексируются не менее хорошо чем текст.

Можно сделать асинхронно подгружаемым автоматически или по требованию пользователя (клику). То есть, после загрузки страницы, запускаем ajax запрос на получение номера телефона. Также можно поставить дополнительные проверки в самом js и на стороне сервера.

Сам код элементарен. В качестве примера:

```
// client
$(function(){
   $('#phone').load('/get_phone.php');
});

// server
function isBot() {

    if ( !(isset($_COOKIE['какая-нибудь-кука']) && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) ) return true;

    return preg_match("/(bot|slurp|mail\.ru)/i", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
}

echo isBot()? '':'+7 (495) 224-22-22';
```

UPD:

[[@sergiks](/users/7161/sergiks)](/users/7161/sergiks) напомнил ещё один вариант.
Обфусцировать номера телефонов и добавлять их на страницу посредством того же js включённого в саму страницу.

Comment: лишний запрос к веб-серверу, удвоенная нагрузка, не айс.

Comment: Эээ... они-то индексируются, но поисковик не станет проводить OCR картинки, делать ему больше нечего.

Comment: 2 метод, т.е. н-р после каждой цифры вставлять букву, а затем с помощью js , н-р регуляркой вырезать только числа?

Answer (score 5):

вот самый маленький из известных мне способов:

CSS:

```
.phone {
   direction:rtl;
   text-align: left;
   unicode-bidi:bidi-override;
}
```

главный минус решения - копируется тоже наоборот

другая идея:

html:

```
<div class="phone">+1 555<p>что нить случайное</p>-9<p>и так несколько раз</p>9-345</div>
```

css:

```
.phone p {
  display: none;
}
```

[демо обоих способов](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/GjWeA/)

Comment: остроумно! Тогда ещё так можно:

    <style>
        i.tel_msk:after{content:"+7 (495) "} 
        i.tel_office:after{content:"555-43-21"}
    </style>
    <i class="tel_msk"></i><i class="tel_office"></i> - офис

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/3cwr6/)

Answer (score 4):

А почему бы не попробовать сделать честно? Положите контактные данные на отдельную страничку (yoursite.org/contacts), и запретите поисковикам индексировать её через robots.txt. Хороший, правильный поисковик не зайдёт, если запрещено.

Заблокировать же от злонамеренного crowler'а невозможно: в худшем случае он сэмулирует cookies и flash, срендерит страницу в картинку и пробежится по ней распознавателем текста, если на то будет воля его создателя.

Comment: Т.е. извлечь из базы н-р id и номер телефона. А из этой страницы как? Регуляркой доставать нужный номер?

Comment: @Радик Камалов: А на этой странице публикуйте в открытом виде.

Comment: [Яндекс рекомендует](http://help.yandex.ru/metrika/?id=1121928) держать контактные данные на каждой странице сайта.

Comment: @sergiks: ну, хм, согласен, смысл есть. Тогда можно поместить контактную информацию в iframe и точно так же заблокировать его для поисковиков через robots.txt.

Comment: @VladD, хорошо, что будет работать с выключенным JS, и вроде, всё честно. Минус тот же — лишний запрос с каждой страницы, и тяжелая страница - iFrame жрёт памяти почти как целый таб.

Comment: @sergiks: на мой вкус, можно поставить приличную expiry date, и браузер закеширует. Так что мы даже уменьшим вес всех страниц -- наверное.

---
Оффтопик: а как вы ставите длинное тире? Есть какое-то заклинание в здешнем варианте makrdown?

Comment: Option + Shift + "минус" (я на маке). А на PC, кажется, Alt+151 (цифры при нажатом альте набирать только на цифровой клавиатуре справа).

Comment: @sergiks: Попробовал Alt+0151 — получилось. Спасибо! На маке как-то почеловечнее выходит, сделать что ли кастомную раскладку под мои форточки?

Answer (score 3):

Банальная обфускация. В теле html содержится запакованная версия нечитаемого ололо, которое преобразуется в телефонный номер Javascript'ом. [Работающий пример](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/3v3bu/).

Такой исходный html, неполезный для поисковиков:

```
<p>Наш телефон: <span class="figvam">dqcpmshuvwpnopq</span></p>
```

преобразуется в браузере в:

```
<p>Наш телефон: <span class="figvam">+7(405)555-5555</span></p>
```

с помощью такого скрипта (набросал наскоро)

```
(function(w,undefined){
    var OBF = {
        offset: 57
        ,range: 11
        ,process: function( s, d){
            var out = '',i;
            for(i=0;i<s.length;i++){
                out += String.fromCharCode(
                    s.charCodeAt(i)
                        + d*this.offset 
                        + d*(i%this.range)
                );
            };
            return out;
        }
        ,encode: function(s){ return this.process(s,  1) }
        ,decode: function(s){ return this.process(s, -1) }
    };
    w.OBF = OBF;
})(window);

var n = '+7 (495) 123-45-67'; // тест
console.log( OBF.encode(n) ); // туда: dq[dqwtiasulgoqjtv
console.log( OBF.decode( OBF.encode(n)) ); // сюда: +7 (495) 123-45-67
```

Тут просто каждый символ телефона замещается по ASCII-таблице на соседние с неким смещением, зависящим от позиции символа в строке.

Comment: Можно же просто н-р умножить на 2 перед выводом, а c js поделить на 2.

Comment: Как будете умножать на 2 скобки и пробелы?

Comment: в БД хранится только число 10значное

Comment: Ещё проще: выводить их в шестнадцатиричном виде, конвертируя Javascript'ом в десятичный для пользователя-с-браузером.

    24CB016EA -> 9876543210
    Javascript:
    telHex = '24CB016EA';    
    telDec = parseInt( telHex, 16);